# 2 вопроса по джаве

Tags: ооп, java

Готовлюсь к собеседованию, и тут сделал для себя пару открытий:

1) Правильно ли я понимаю, что equals() для пользовательского класса по дефолту будет всегда возвращать false, пока его не переопределишь?

2) И, получается, когда пишешь что-то типа такого

```
public class HelloWorld{

    public static class Lol {
        private int a;

        Lol(int a) {
            this.a = a;
        }

        public boolean equals(Lol other){
            return this.a == other.a;
        }
    }

     public static void main(String []args){
        Lol lol1 = new Lol(1);
        Lol lol2 = new Lol(2);
        System.out.println(lol1.equals(lol2));
     }
}
```

внутри метода equals() можно получить доступ даже к private полям аргумента. Это почему так?

Comment: Внутри одного класса можно обращаться к закрытым полям этого же класса. А вы попробуйте раскидать их по разным файлам. Удастся ли тогда?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Правильно ли я понимаю, что equals() для пользовательского класса по дефолту будет всегда возвращать false, пока его не переопределишь?

Метод equals наследуется от класса Object и работает следующим образом:

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

То есть возвращает true в случае, если x и y ссылаются на один объект. Следовательно, пока equals не будет переопределен, это поведение сохранится, а следовательно, даже несмотря на равенство всех полей в двух экземплярах, результатом выполнения equals будет false, если сравниваемые объекты не являются одним и тем же объектом в памяти (в противном случае результатом будет все-таки true).

Важная ремарка: если вы предъявите этот код на собеседовании, то, весьма вероятно, получите в ответ вопрос, не забыли ли вы также переопределить метод hashCode. Правильный ответ - забыли, эти два метода всегда идут в связке друг с другом. В частности, в C# (в java не знаю, возможно, тоже) при переопределении только Equals вы получите предупреждение от компилятора о том, что неплохо было бы переопределить и GetHashCode.

> 2) И, получается, когда пишешь что-то типа такого (...) внутри метода equals() можно получить доступ даже к private полям аргумента. Это почему так?

Разумеется, класс внутри своих собственных  может обращаться к собственым же приватным полям (иначе в чем был бы смысл их существования). Тут стоит понимать, что приватность обеспечивается по отношению к классу "вообще", а не к конкретным экземплярам. То есть из любого экземпляра класса Foo вы можете получить доступ к приватным челенам любого другого экземпляра того же класса, но не можете получить таковой доступ из экземпляров других классов.

**UPD:**
На самом деле это имеет очень большой практический смысл - есть очень много ситуаций, когда экземпляр класса должен взаимодействовать с другими экземплярами того же класса и иметь доступ к их членам. Примером может служить все тот же equals (вполне логично, что для корректного сравнения двух экземпляров необходимо проводить сравнения их внутренных данных), конструктор копирования или различные операции, связанные со сравнением. Если бы такой возможности не было, то для реализации подобных методов потребовалось бы выносить часть внутренней логики наружу, делая приватные поля публичными или давая внешнему коду доступ к ним через геттеры/сеттеры, что зачастую губительно или просто ненужно.

Comment: А вам спасибо за последний абзац, я почему-то думал, что приватность обеспечивается по отношению к конкретным экземпляром.  
  
И спасибо за ремарку про hashCode.

Comment: @Dazar, прочтите, пожалуйста, последний абзац еще раз, там я добавил довольно важное дополнение относително того, зачем нужно именно так.

Comment: @DreamChild, спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

> equals() для пользовательского класса по дефолту будет всегда возвращать false, пока его не переопределишь?

Нет, не всегда. Реализация `equals` в `java.lang.Object` выглядит следующим образом:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

Таким образом, дефолтная реализация `equals` возвращает `true` в случае, если оба объекта ссылаются на одну и ту же область памяти, проще говоря — если сравнивается объект с самим собой.

> внутри метода equals() можно получить доступ даже к private полям аргумента. Это почему так?

И что же вас вас удивляет в том, что внутри метода класса можно получить доступ к приватным полям этого же класса?

P.S. Кстати говоря, в вашем примере вы не переопределили `equals`. Проще говоря, создали не `overrided method`, а `overloaded method`. А поскольку `overriden` методы выбираются в рантайме, то, например, с коллекциями ваш `equals` не будет вызываться (из-за `type erasure`). Измените тип аргумента на `Object`.

Comment: А, да, спасибо за PS, обычно я в через IDE это делаю, а сейчас просто по памяти набрал).

Answer (score 0):

1.equals() для пользовательского класса по дефолту сравнивает ссылки, поэтому нужно его писать вручную или средствами IDE.